# SQL: FULLTEXT Index for speed

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing, bigdata

More than ten million rows, painfully slow. Currently using 'LIKE' to count the number of hits:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE `job` LIKE '%sales%' AND `location` LIKE '%New York%'
```

Am I correct in thinking that I want to:

(1) Apply FULLTEXT index to each field

(2) Use a CONTAINS statement to increase speed:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE contains('location', '"New York"') and contains ('job',"sales")
```

Would this produce identical results to my initial LIKE query?

Would this be many times faster, with the only downside being a huge increase in the storage size of the database?

Example: I want to count data like this: "sales manager", "Buffalo, New York"

Comment: The standard relational database index is a btree.  Btrees can not be used for any query that involves wildcard + word as in  `LIKE '%sales'.`  Indexes can be used for `LIKE word%`.  So what you are experiencing is a full table scan.  It's good to get familiar with EXPLAIN so you can review and understand this problem yourself.    MySQL full text indexes are an option here, but they have tradeoffs.  You really need to read up on how they work, and concepts like "stop words" and minimum word length.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. So if I want to replicate the "LIKE" search, but simply make it faster and avoid a full table scan. I just need to create a FULLTEXT index for each of the ten fields that I have. Is this practicable, given that I have 10 million rows and that some of the fields have 100+ words / 1,000+ characters?

Comment: As Rick James already posted, your search can only use one index.  If your requirement simply can't utilize the benefits of a relational database, you might be better off using one of the fulltext search engines that exist.  The MySQL full text indexes are fine but more of an addon when most of the data is structured, but you have an exception you still want to search.  Elastic Search, Lucene/Solr and Sphinx might fit better.  Another option to look at would be MongoDB, which is a document database.  It has good fulltext, but is a document database which might fit your origin data better.

Comment: @gview Thanks, but are you sure I can't have more than one index? What I am doing is very standard: I have ten fields with text data similar to LinkedIn (job, location, country, email...) I have around ten million rows. What I want is basically LinkedIn style functionality, where you can search by title, country, etc. Any additional clarification hugely appreciated.

Comment: Not that you can't have more than one fulltext index, but for a single query, mysql will use one.  Again, check out `EXPLAIN query`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this index to your table:

```
FULLTEXT (location, job)
```

The use this `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE MATCH(location, job) AGAINST("sales manager new york")
```

It will work immensely faster.

**More**

If you have lots of columns with "text", and the search may include stuff from any or all of them, it *may* be better to add an extra column with all the text lumped together.  Then have a `FULLTEXT` index on just that column and `MATCH` against just that column.

Be aware that `FULLTEXT` does not handles numbers or inequalities.  Nor does it handle "short" words or "stop "words.

Comment: Thanks Mr. James, so you are saying that I want one FULLTEXT index for multiple fields, rather than ten FULLTEXT indexes (I have ten fields)

Comment: @NedHulton - Yes.  MySQL will [usually] use only one index.

Comment: @NedHulton - And I added more to my answer since you are _now_ implying that there are more than two columns to search in.

Comment: What is the structure of your database, and what is the nature of the data.  Why would you have 10 fields that all have phrases that need to be searched?  See my prior comment to you about standard indexed LIKE searches that will still use an index.

Comment: Name: John Smith, Location: Saratoga, New York, Country: United States, Job: Sales Associate, Experience: For twenty years, I have done this and that blah blah blah, I have worked in Alabama, New York and Florida.

Comment: @Rick-James Could I have multiple FULLTEXT indexes if I wanted to search "New York" as the location and prevent "Journalist at New York Times" etc. and other data from the "job" field polluting the results?

Comment: @NedHulton - Sounds like it is a raw ascii transcript of a resume?  That sounds like it is already a single `TEXT` column?

Comment: @NedHulton - Yes, separate indexes.  But you _will_ get pollution from other anomalies.

Comment: No, its not a database of resumes, its similar to LinkedIn, with location, country, name, email, phone number, experience. The fields are all in VARCHAR, mostly short, with a longer "experience" field. Maybe I can make life easier by dropping the big experience field and making it read only.

Comment: "read only"????

Comment: No, I just meant, only make the short fields like job title, location, country, searchable and drop the big "experience" field, because its about 1000 characters on average. Maybe, creating a FULLTEXT index of that would take forever. Display it to users when the other fields match, but remove the search functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Q: Am I correct in thinking that I want to apply FULLTEXT index to each field and replace the query with something like this to increase speed?

A: *Yes, you're correct at adding index to make improve the performance.*

---

Q: Am I correct in thinking that this would produce identical results to my LIKE query?

A: *I'm not sure cause I couldn't find any clause related to CONTAINS in MySQL. But please refer [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html) as a solution for full-text indexs.*

---

Q: Am I correct in thinking that this would be many times faster, with the only downside being a huge increase in the storage size of the database?

A: *Well, honestly speaking, it is not a good idea. Because text is unpredictable, it is not a good idea using text as index.*

---

You might choose already your mind regardless of my thinking. But I hope you find another column for lower risk and lower cost to indexing.
Thanks.